# How do you store and access information in an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Short Question: How do I access information inside of each property of an array?

Long explanation: I am new to coding and attempting to create an app that will allow you to play Black Jack. I am currently trying to access the value of each card and struggling to find a way. Can I access the value in the current setup? How? Is there a better way to organize my data?

Thanks.

```
var deck = [
  {card: "Two of Clubs", value: 2},
  {card: "Three of Clubs", value: 3},
  {card: "Four of Clubs", value: 4},
  {card: "Five of Clubs", value: 5},
  {card: "Six of Clubs", value: 6},
  {card: "Seven of Clubs", value: 7},
  {card: "Eight of Clubs", value: 8},
  {card: "Nine of Clubs", value: 9},
  {card: "Ten of Clubs", value: 10},
  {card: "Jack of Clubs", value: 10},
  {card: "Queen of Clubs", value: 10},
  {card: "King of Clubs", value: 10},
  {card: "Ace of Clubs", value: 11},
  {card: "Two of Hearts", value: 2},
  {card: "Three of Hearts", value: 3},
  {card: "Four of Hearts", value: 4},
  {card: "Five of Hearts", value: 5},
  {card: "Six of Hearts", value: 6},
  {card: "Seven of Hearts", value: 7},
  {card: "Eight of Hearts", value: 8},
  {card: "Nine of Hearts", value: 9},
  {card: "Ten of Hearts", value: 10},
  {card: "Jack of Hearts", value: 10},
  {card: "Queen of Hearts", value: 10},
  {card: "King of Hearts", value: 10},
  {card: "Ace of Hearts", value: 11},
  {card: "Two of Spades", value: 2},
  {card: "Three of Spades", value: 3},
  {card: "Four of Spades", value: 4},
  {card: "Five of Spades", value: 5},
  {card: "Six of Spades", value: 6},
  {card: "Seven of Spades", value: 7},
  {card: "Eight of Spades", value: 8},
  {card: "Nine of Spades", value: 9},
  {card: "Ten of Spades", value: 10},
  {card: "Jack of Spades", value: 10},
  {card: "Queen of Spades", value: 10},
  {card: "King of Spades", value: 10},
  {card: "Ace of Spades", value: 11},
  {card: "Two of Diamonds", value: 2},
  {card: "Three of Diamonds", value: 3},
  {card: "Four of Diamonds", value: 4},
  {card: "Five of Diamonds", value: 5},
  {card: "Six of Diamonds", value: 6},
  {card: "Seven of Diamonds", value: 7},
  {card: "Eight of Diamonds", value: 8},
  {card: "Nine of Diamonds", value: 9},
  {card: "Ten of Diamonds", value: 10},
  {card: "Jack of Diamonds", value: 10},
  {card: "Queen of Diamonds", value: 10},
  {card: "King of Diamonds", value: 10},
  {card: "Ace of Diamonds", value: 11}
]

function draw(i) {
  var drawn = i[Math.floor(Math.random()*i.length)];
  console.log(drawn);
}

var playerCard1 = draw(deck);
var dealerCard1 = draw(deck);
var playerCard2 = draw(deck);
var dealerCard2 = draw(deck);

var player = playerCard1.value + playerCard2.value;
console.log(player);
```

Comment: `playerCard1.value`, not `value.playerCard1` :)

Answer (score 0):

Your draw method needs to return something.

```
var deck = [
{card: "Two of Clubs", value: 2},
{card: "Three of Clubs", value: 3},
{card: "Four of Clubs", value: 4},
{card: "Five of Clubs", value: 5},
{card: "Six of Clubs", value: 6},
{card: "Seven of Clubs", value: 7},
{card: "Eight of Clubs", value: 8},
{card: "Nine of Clubs", value: 9},
{card: "Ten of Clubs", value: 10},
{card: "Jack of Clubs", value: 10},
{card: "Queen of Clubs", value: 10},
{card: "King of Clubs", value: 10},
{card: "Ace of Clubs", value: 11},
{card: "Two of Hearts", value: 2},
{card: "Three of Hearts", value: 3},
{card: "Four of Hearts", value: 4},
{card: "Five of Hearts", value: 5},
{card: "Six of Hearts", value: 6},
{card: "Seven of Hearts", value: 7},
{card: "Eight of Hearts", value: 8},
{card: "Nine of Hearts", value: 9},
{card: "Ten of Hearts", value: 10},
{card: "Jack of Hearts", value: 10},
{card: "Queen of Hearts", value: 10},
{card: "King of Hearts", value: 10},
{card: "Ace of Hearts", value: 11},
{card: "Two of Spades", value: 2},
{card: "Three of Spades", value: 3},
{card: "Four of Spades", value: 4},
{card: "Five of Spades", value: 5},
{card: "Six of Spades", value: 6},
{card: "Seven of Spades", value: 7},
{card: "Eight of Spades", value: 8},
{card: "Nine of Spades", value: 9},
{card: "Ten of Spades", value: 10},
{card: "Jack of Spades", value: 10},
{card: "Queen of Spades", value: 10},
{card: "King of Spades", value: 10},
{card: "Ace of Spades", value: 11},
{card: "Two of Diamonds", value: 2},
{card: "Three of Diamonds", value: 3},
{card: "Four of Diamonds", value: 4},
{card: "Five of Diamonds", value: 5},
{card: "Six of Diamonds", value: 6},
{card: "Seven of Diamonds", value: 7},
{card: "Eight of Diamonds", value: 8},
{card: "Nine of Diamonds", value: 9},
{card: "Ten of Diamonds", value: 10},
{card: "Jack of Diamonds", value: 10},
{card: "Queen of Diamonds", value: 10},
{card: "King of Diamonds", value: 10},
{card: "Ace of Diamonds", value: 11}
]

function draw(i) {
var drawn = i[Math.floor(Math.random()*i.length)];
// console.log(drawn);
return drawn;  // you need to return something!!! 
}

var playerCard1 = draw(deck);
var dealerCard1 = draw(deck);
var playerCard2 = draw(deck);
var dealerCard2 = draw(deck);

var player = playerCard1.value + playerCard2.value;
console.log(player);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that since the function was creating a variable, I could access the variable immediately.

Answer (score 0):

first of all :

your deck should be like this

```
var deck = [
{"card": "Two of Clubs", "value": 2},
{"card": "Three of Clubs", "value": 3},
]
```

if you notice, the words card and value are in quotes

next:

in the function draw(),

```
return drawn
```

at last:

```
var player = playerCard1['value'] + playerCard2['value']
```

Comment: No, `card` and `value` do **not** need to be in quotes. Also, in general, `playerCard1.value` is preferred to `playerCard1['value']`. At least jslint thinks so.

Comment: ohh my bad ! I am still thinking python !!

Answer (score 0):

You should think of a more efficient way to set this data.

I can think of a function for retrieving the value given the card (i haven't tested!):

```
function getCardValue( number, symbol ) {
var currCard;
   for(var i=0; i < deck.length ; ++i) {
   currCard = deck[i];
       if(currCard.card == number + " of " + symbol )
       return currCard.value;
   }
};

// you use like this
getCardValue("eight", "diamonds"); // 8
```

It works, but it's too troublesome for a simple issue. Besides, it would be better for the function to receive the values as `int`s. An alternative, since a deck of cards have a hierarchy of symbol/number, could be:

```
var deck = { // 
    clubs: [ // array
        {value:2} // 0
        {value:1} // 1
        {value:4} // 2
        ...
        {value:3} // 11 = king
    ],
    spades: [...],
    hearts: [...],
    diamonds: [...]
}
// you access a value like this
deck.clubs[11].value // 3
```

For returning the value based on a string like "Eight of spades" you'd have to write a function extracting the number and the symbol from the string as an argument, and return `deck[symbol][number].value`.

There are several other ways for performing this.

Answer (score 0):

To access an array, you need to know how arrays work, arrays are a list of items that store value, in this case, on objects. To access arrays, you need to write the variable name followed by the [] within the [] you need to write the index number which in mathematics starts from 1 but in coding, it will start from 0. So to access the first item in the array, you will need to write `array_name[0]` because it first item is stored as index 0.

Going to the object, the object must be accessed by this format `object_name.property` with the dot followed by the property.

Now in your example, if you want to access Two of Clubs, you can do `deck[0].card` Here I combined the both array's get property and object's get property to get the Two of Clubs property.

Similarly, with the second item, to get Three of Cubes, it is`deck[1].card`. You can get the value property too like this `deck[0].value` or `deck[1].value`.

Answer (score -1):

Just access the value property of the array element.

For instance, let's say you want to access the value of "Six of Clubs"

```
var sixOfClubsVal = deck[4].value
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not trying to access the data directly from the array, but access it from the drawn card.